# How do I fix my check-multisig if-else output script?

Tags: script, multi-signature, input-script

I'm trying to create a custom script with if/else and a multisig operation in one branch. Currently, my script looks thus:

```
OP_IF
    <pub1>
    OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
    OP_2
    <pub2>
    <pub3>
    <pub4>
    OP_3
    OP_CHECKMULTISIG
OP_ENDIF
```

I have calculated a testnet address (`2NF3yXy2MambEnJuY7eStLNcX92WSxytLvC`) from this example script and sent testcoin there. Then, I tried spending the money with the following sig script:

```
OP_0 <sig2> <sig3> <redeemScript>
```

However, when trying to broadcast the transaction, I get an error:

> PUSH TRANSACTION ERROR: 16: MANDATORY-SCRIPT-VERIFY-FLAG-FAILED
>   (SIGNATURE MUST BE ZERO FOR FAILED CHECK(MULTI)SIG OPERATION)

For reference, here's my raw transaction:

```
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
```

Its sig script is this:

```
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
```

Which decodes to

> 0
>   3045022100f502ecfd2b7bbb3e7092b320c568abe0d68dd7e613ab3efcb9e479b2641a73a502202b416bb86bce3d242084f8e24cbed76e5a2c5a0795a5bbd7f3366bf6d086ae4f[ALL]
>   304402201022c7548b55f3fbe3ddf427ad2ae5c6a776e2a63ee25376dca123d53d0f940f022041aa7967208ee8aee1811f02d6c7db0ad2872304133d46dbdd117e9bc09d8c97[ALL]
>   632102bc050e51811c2c454bf3487129b19d60b87f7a51fb434e6073def19dc55cf4b3ac67522102a906b96ea2df77aff1f84cc9949550f8d6b8f3db5acd625d12d70b6da4b94b1e2102046e854e69a49dd210dbf554f1e420893935b47123667a1834def9fe5d44358a210325db22e2aef6f143026500522431d4f348f911562316350852e6382da6a048a753ae68

The last line is clearly visible as the redeem script, which in turn decodes to this:

> OP_IF
>   02bc050e51811c2c454bf3487129b19d60b87f7a51fb434e6073def19dc55cf4b3
>   OP_CHECKSIG OP_ELSE 2
>   02a906b96ea2df77aff1f84cc9949550f8d6b8f3db5acd625d12d70b6da4b94b1e
>   02046e854e69a49dd210dbf554f1e420893935b47123667a1834def9fe5d44358a
>   0325db22e2aef6f143026500522431d4f348f911562316350852e6382da6a048a7 3
>   OP_CHECKMULTISIG OP_ENDIF

Is my sig script incorrect? Is the output script invalid? How can I fix this and make it work?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: After taking into consideration Pieter's comment but placing the extra OP_0 right after the two signatures in the sig script, it worked. Here's the new decoded sig script:

> 0
>   3045022100f502ecfd2b7bbb3e7092b320c568abe0d68dd7e613ab3efcb9e479b2641a73a502202b416bb86bce3d242084f8e24cbed76e5a2c5a0795a5bbd7f3366bf6d086ae4f[ALL]
>   304402201022c7548b55f3fbe3ddf427ad2ae5c6a776e2a63ee25376dca123d53d0f940f022041aa7967208ee8aee1811f02d6c7db0ad2872304133d46dbdd117e9bc09d8c97[ALL]
>   0
>   632102bc050e51811c2c454bf3487129b19d60b87f7a51fb434e6073def19dc55cf4b3ac67522102a906b96ea2df77aff1f84cc9949550f8d6b8f3db5acd625d12d70b6da4b94b1e2102046e854e69a49dd210dbf554f1e420893935b47123667a1834def9fe5d44358a210325db22e2aef6f143026500522431d4f348f911562316350852e6382da6a048a753ae68

And here's the link to the transaction: https://testnet.smartbit.com.au/tx/1894cb91fde60432e59d60f30de503e8b6fbe5d1756bbf0ef7302b57bf31d195

Comment: I believe you may need two `OP_0`'s at the start: one to be consumed by `OP_IF`, and one which is popped off by `OP_CHECKMULTISIG`. I'll turn this into a full answer once I've identified the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I just tried it, and I'm still getting the same error: `PUSH TRANSACTION ERROR: 16: MANDATORY-SCRIPT-VERIFY-FLAG-FAILED (SIGNATURE MUST BE ZERO FOR FAILED CHECK(MULTI)SIG OPERATION)`

Comment: ~30min in the Video Andreas explains the „IF“ handling of script. There must be a value before the IF statement. Either 1 for the If-branch or a 0 for the else branch. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yU3Sr07Qnxg

Comment: @pebwindkraft: that should be an answer. ;)

Comment: @murch: not chasing for credits anymore :-) Pieter and you have provided the answers, and this is just "a little bit" additional explanation, which might help the users to better understand the previous comments.

Comment: @pebwindkraft: Fair enough. However, it's not only about the reputation, it's also that comments shouldn't be used to answer questions. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OP_IF` consumes a number from the top of the stack.
The `OP_IF` will evaluate to `true` if the number is `not 0`, and to `false` if the number is `0`.

<sup>H/T for [this answer by David Schwartz](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2318/5406), and  to Pieter Wuille for getting me on the right track.</sup>